# Table on top of an image in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm quite new to bootstrap and i've come across this problem. I would like to have a background image in my carousel on top of which i would put content like a table or such. This is what i've written so far.

```
 <div class="item active">
            <div class="row" id="redak1">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6" id="bg">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                     <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla">
                         <tr class="info">
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                          </tr>

                        </table></div>
                 </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

And my CSS is this:

```
#bg {

    height: 768px;
  }
#tabla {

  border:solid black;
  margin-top:150px;
  height:500px;
}

#redak1 {
  background-image:url('../img/grass.jpg');
  width:1024px;
  margin:auto;
}

.carousel table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}
```

(all the div tags and carousel-inner class are included but I did not post them here)

This code does, more or less, what i want but there are some problems. When i scale the browser window down the content (the picture and the table) does not scale with it. How can I make it work? I suppose there is a way better way for doing this but this is what i mannaged to do. Any help is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your fixed width on your `#redak1` element.

Here is a way to achieve something like what you want :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/120630

**HTML** :

```
 <div class="item active">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6" id="bg">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="tabla">
                     <tbody><tr class="info">
                        <td>bla</td>
                        <td>bla</td>
                        <td>bla</td>
                        <td>bla</td>
                      </tr>

                    </tbody></table></div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```